# Conditional formatting to entire row

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a code in C# with EPPLUS for Excel that fills a cell green if the value of the cell is over 100. It works:

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("G4:G" + (c.Count + 4));    
string _statement = "IF(G4>100,1,0)";
var _cond2 = hoja.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond2.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
_cond2.Formula = _statement;
```

But what I really need is to fill the entire row. If I change the range:

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("A4:G" + (c.Count + 4));
```

Applies only for the cells in the A column, not to the entire row.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the reference to `G4` absolute otherwise the formula will be apply relative to that cell.  So change this line:

```
string _statement = "IF(G4>100,1,0)";
```

to apply to the entire row based ONLY on `G4`

```
string _statement = "IF($G$4>100,1,0)";
```

**(Response to Comments)**

to apply to entire rows relative to row number but keep the column fixed to G:

```
string _statement = "IF($G4>100,1,0)";
```

Comment: First thanks for the answer. But this not work for me, i need to see if the value of the G4,G5,G6,G7......... cells is >100 and if true apply the format to entire Row of the cell taht contain the number greater tan 100. And when i aply your answer dont apply the format to any cell (perhaps they watch on ly in the G4 cell???),( or perhaps i need to use absolute reference in the range???)

Comment: @Ion Ok. so do you mean you want to have the row number relative but the column letter absolute?  See my edit above.

Comment: PERFECT, you are awesome